# 301 Redirect to site without .htaccess (myshopify.com) & SEO rank issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo, html4

History/Context:  I have a site, 'www.oldexample.com' built in 1998, HTML 4.01 transitional on Apache, cpanel server. Until last fall our main keywords got us to top 10. After mobile changes and Panda etc, Dropped to page 2 or 3 for all but one very specific keyword. The old site, 'www.oldexample.com' has many good back links and history in google and all main directories. I am rebuilding a test site now which is on 'mycompany.myshopify.com' as it addresses all my google errors issues on oldsite. I have set up my 'www.newexample.com' to redirect to the shopify site which is called up under 'www.newexample.com'.The myshopify.com URL does not show up at all.

Question:  If I were to do cpanel 301 redirect of whole 'oldexample.com' to 'newexample.com' would I still benefit from the many links and history of oldsite?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that the shopify URL doesn't show at all, do you mean it's not showing when you search for those keywords, or it's not indexed at all? If it's the latter, prompt Google to index it using Google Search Console. If it's the former, there are a number of things that could have affected this:

- the authority of the new site - if you've just launched it, it naturally won't have the authority of the previous site and therefore is less likely to get visibility
- you are correct that the backlinks would have played a major part in this. What you need to do is to redirect the old domain to the new one you want to appear in Google. For example, if you want to actually take people to newsite.shopify.com, you should redirect the old domain directly to that one. If you redirect the old one to newdomain.com, which you then redirect to newsite.shopify.com the result won't be the same. Link value is lost via redirects. Ideally, you should get in touch with as many 3rd party websites linking to your old domain and ask them to update the links to point to newsite.shopify.com

Even if you do that you might still not see those rankings because of various other factors. If you fancy posting the actual URLs and keywords in question, I can spare a few minutes to have a look.

Comment: ,Thank you. Old domain (since 1998) is [link](http://www.yokodana.com) . New one (which is actually the shopify site) is [link](http://yokodanakimono.com). Any help would be appreciated. My email is yokodana.usa_atsign_gmailDOTcom Dana Lewis